# Everit schema builder includes unset properties as null

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, everit

Trying to build and use the Schema object:

```
        Schema rootSchema = ObjectSchema.builder()
                .additionalProperties(true)
                .build();
```

It seems to work fine until I try to serialize it as a string and then to reload using the SchemaLoader:

```
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootSchema);
        JSONObject schemaObject = new JSONObject(json);
        Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(schemaObject);
```

The problem is that the unset keywords are serialized as null:

```
{
  "title" : null,
  "description" : null,
  "id" : null,
  "propertySchemas" : { },
  "schemaOfAdditionalProperties" : null,
  "requiredProperties" : [ ],
  "minProperties" : null,
  "maxProperties" : null,
  "propertyDependencies" : { },
  "schemaDependencies" : { },
  "patternProperties" : { }
}
```

The SchemaLoader reports these as errors, e.g. "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not a string." Would it be possible to skip these keywords?

Another problem: the serialized version doesn't include the additionalProperties keyword.

Also, is it possible to include additional keywords, not specified in the JSON Schema spec? AFAIIK the spec itself doesn't prohibit such keywords, and some libraries such as AJV actually use them?

Comment: I just noticed that the builder generates keywords which are not compliant with the JSON Schema specification, e.g. allItemSchema instead of items. So it is probably not suitable as a general purpose schema generator.

Comment: Plus one to the above, with the weight of one of the spec editors. Are you sure the tool your using is trying to build actual JSON Schema?

Comment: I was following this advise by the creator of everit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38478478/6871028 
Given my observations so far, apparently the answer is no.

Comment: As a spec editor, could you advise a Java generator to build a schema from scratch? There are quite few libraries for code-based generation but I am struggling to find a simple schema builder that meets the spec.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot. I don't know Java. Take a look at http://json-schema.org/implementations.html and / or come by our Slack and ask. There are others that use Java there.

Comment: Thanks, joined and asked.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to serialize the schema instance with jackson (like `String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootSchema);`) won't work, since it will dump the internals of the schema object (which will actually be quite similar to a json schema, but not exactly).

Instead, you have to serialize the schema object to schema json by calling `String json = rootSchema.toString();`